# Javascript - HowTo encode a floating point in binary with IEEE 754

Tags: javascript, ieee-754, stl-format

I'm currently writing on an **STL-Splitter**, based on three.js STLLoader.js.
This little Tool should parse a [STL-File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29) and save the floating points to an array.
After this I look up which triangles are connected and save them to an string, which I send to an Server which creates a new STL File (with PHP).
This actually works.

But after decoding the binary file and saving the floating points, I have no idea **how to convert the floating points back to the correct format** like this:

```
UINT8[80] – Header
UINT32 – Number of triangles

foreach triangle
REAL32[3] – Normal vector
REAL32[3] – Vertex 1
REAL32[3] – Vertex 2
REAL32[3] – Vertex 3
UINT16 – Attribute byte count
end
```

Currently I write it in ASCII-Format, doesnt matter which format you have.
Maybe a little example or a keyword (which i can search for) could help.

Thanks for your Help ! (Sry if this is a "noob"-Question :/ )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in which language do you want to solve this but in javascript/node.js you have to  create `buffer` with fixed size. Into the buffer you can add header (84 bytes) and then faces with normals. Use `buf.writeFloatLE()` function. In the end you can write whole buffer to file or do anything you want with it.